# created Jenkins environment in ec2 ubuntu instance

Tags: amazon-ec2

created Jenkins environment  in ec2 ubuntu instance 
and created drupal instance in another ec2 instance how to transfer files from jenkins environment to  drupal environmen

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question is unclear and it is not clear what you are trying to do. Could you please update your question with more details, including what you have tried to do so far?

Answer (score 1):

I am not good in linux skills. If you are windows user. You can use **WinSCP** in your windows OS. You can login jenkins linux os and drupal linux os for files transfer. You can achieve file copying between linux system in this way.

Another way is to use linux commands.

http://www.mpipks-dresden.mpg.de/~mueller/docs/suse10.2/html/opensuse-manual_en/manual/sec.filetrans.copy.html

Hope it helps!!!